# How to implement "or" operator in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been trying to implement the `"or"` operator in elasticsearch query.
i have 3 documents with field and value as given below

```
dummyText : birthday party

dummyText : birthday morning one

dummyText : birthday evening two
```

I use the match query as

```
{
   "query": {
        "match": {
          "dummyText": {
             "operator": "or",
             "query": "birthday evening"
             }
           }
       }
}
```

It returns only one document which matches `"birthday evening"`. why isn't it returning all the documents which has value "birthday"? Please, guide me on this.

Comment: What analyzer that you applied for "dummyText" when indexing/searching ? Standard ? It should return 3 records when using Standard Analyzer

Comment: I agree with the above comment. I also just tried it and got all three docs back. Maybe you are indexing all three docs with same id and they override each other?

Comment: Im using custom analyzer with nGram filter

Comment: What are the index time analyzers and search time analyzers. The first two comments are spot on. What does this "custom analyzer" look like?

Comment: "analyzer": {
        "str_index_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase", 
            "substring"
          ], 
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }, 
        "str_search_analyzer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ], 
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      }, 
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "max_gram": 20, 
          "min_gram": 3, 
          "type": "nGram"
        }
      }

Comment: it is due to keyword tokenizer i have used in search analyzer...it's considering the search input text as single word...it works as expected with standard analyzer..thanks all for your help..